# Can't connect to localhost of the host machine from inside of my Docker container

Tags: docker, ubuntu, localhost

The question is basic: how to I connect to the localhost of the host machine from inside of a Docker container?

I tried answers from [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24319662/from-inside-of-a-docker-container-how-do-i-connect-to-the-localhost-of-the-mach), using `add-host host.docker.internal:host-gateway` or writing `--network=host` when running my container but none of these methods seem to work.

I have a simple *hello world* webserver up on my machine, and I can see it's contents with `curl localhost:8000` from my host, but I can't curl it from inside the container. I tried `curl host.docker.internal:8000`, curl `localhost:8000`, and `curl 127.0.0.1:8000` from inside the container (based on the solution I used to make localhost available there) but none of them seem to work and I get a `Connection refused` error every time.

I asked somebody else to try this out for me on their own machine and it worked for them, so I don't think I'm doing anything wrong.

Does anybody have any idea what is wrong with my containers?

Host machine: Ubuntu 20.04.01

Docker version: 20.10.7

Used image: Ubuntu 20.04 (and i386/ubuntu18.04)

Comment: How is this question different from the canonical question you link to?  How is the service on the host set up; does it only listen on the 127.0.0.1 `lo0` interface or on 0.0.0.0 all interfaces?

Comment: Those methods didn't work for me so I thought my problem is something else than that answer. It listens on 0.0.0.0. Here's my code: https://pastebin.ubuntu.com/p/dpf4VB8tRP/ @DavidMaze

Comment: I also tried it with ```python3 -m http.server``` which sets up a web server on 0.0.0.0 port 8000 and it still doesn't work so I'm sure I don't have a bug in my webserver. @DavidMaze

Comment: same problem for me... same host machine version and docker version, host.docker.internal:xxxx not works even with `host.docker.internal:host-gateway` option... it resolves to 172.17.0.1 but not working due to bridge docker0 has no interface and containers attached and other bridges are created with docker-compose... my docker container is using 172.19.0.2 for eth0 but not works too as docker0 is DOWN ( based on ifconfig)... I want to connect to java REST under localhost:7777, works with postman, from docker container not... some ubuntu networking related bug?

Answer (score 2):

### Temporary solution

This does not completely solve the problem for production purposes, but at least in order to get the localhost working, by adding these lines into `docker-compose.yml` it solved my issue for now ([source](https://www.cloudsavvyit.com/14114/how-to-connect-to-localhost-within-a-docker-container/)):

```
services:
  my-service:
    network_mode: host
```

I am using apache nifi to use Java REST endpoints with the same ubuntu and docker versions, so in my case, it looks like this:

```
services:
  nifi:
    network_mode: host
```

After changing `docker-compose.yml`, I recommend stopping docker container, removing containers(`docker-compose rm` - do not use if you need some containers, otherwise use `docker container rm container_id`) and build with `docker-compose up --build` again.

In this case, I needed to use another localhost IP for my service to access with a browser (nifi started on other ip - `127.0.1.1` but works fine as well).

### Searching for the problem / deeper into ubuntu-docker networking

Firstly, I will write down some useful commands that may be useful to find out a solution for the docker-ubuntu networking issue:

- `ip a` - show all routing, network devices, interfaces and tunnels (mainly I can observe `state DOWN` with `docker0`)
- `ifconfig` - list all interfaces
- `brctl show` - ethernet bridge administration (docker0 has no attached interface / veth pair)
- `docker network ls` - manages docker networks - names, drivers, scope...
- `docker network inspect bridge` - I can see for docker0 bridge has no attached docker containers - empty and not used bridge

([useful link for ubuntu-docker networking explanation](https://dumlutimuralp.medium.com/docker-networking-intro-62d4bc163843))

[image]

I guess that problem lays within `veth pair` (see link above), because when docker-compose occurs, there is a new bridge created (not `docker0`) that is connected to `veth pair` in my case, and docker0 is not used. My guess is that if `docker0` is used, then `host.docker.internal:host-gateway` would work. Somehow in ubuntu networking, there is `docker0` not used as the default bridge and this maybe should be changed.

I don't have much time left actually, well, I suppose someone can use this information and resolve the core of the problem later on.